# Changing Animation target

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Can't switch animation from one object to another. The id changes (it prints 'world' in log), but it doesn't transfer the animation: `hello` still flashing and `world` is static.

It works correctly only when calling `a.restart()`. When there are no functions, just bindings, you can use `onChanged` and control how the animation stops (complete or pause) `if (running) { complete(); restart(); }`.

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Column {
    ColorAnimation {
        id: a

        target: lab1
        property: "color"

        running: true
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        duration: 500

        from: "black"
        to: "red"
    }

    Text {
        id: lab1

        text: "hello"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                a.target = lab2
                console.log("changed")
                console.log(a.target.text)
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: lab2

        text: "world"
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug (or at the very least a documentation issue) so file a bug report at bugreports.qt.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use this for now (just added onTargetChanged):

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Column {
    ColorAnimation {
        id: a

        target: lab1

        onTargetChanged: {
            if (running) { complete(); restart(); }
        }

        property: "color"

        running: true
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        duration: 500

        from: "black"
        to: "red"
    }

    Text {
        id: lab1

        text: "hello"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                a.target = lab2
                console.log("changed")
                console.log(a.target.text)
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: lab2

        text: "world"
    }
}
```

And with binding (animation is switched to another label when pressed):

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Column {
    id: root

    ColorAnimation {
        id: a

        target: ma.pressed ? lab2 : lab1

        onTargetChanged: {
            if (running) { complete(); restart(); }
        }

        property: "color"

        running: true
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        duration: 500

        from: "black"
        to: "red"
    }

    Text {
        id: lab1

        text: "hello"

        MouseArea {
            id: ma
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: lab2

        text: "world"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stop the animation before changing the target:

```
a.running = false
a.target = lab2
a.running = true
```

It works fine for me

Comment: In binding there is no possibility to do that.

Comment: What do you mean? You just can replace `a.target = lab2` with my code and that's all.

Comment: Look into the second part of the response with `onTargetChanged`. There is no `onClick` to stick code there. And my actual project doesn't have `onClick` either.